# How do I ensure a relationship is commutative and unique?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, unique-constraint, computed-column

In PostgreSQL, we can ensure the relations stored inside a table a commutative-ly (or bidirectional etc) unique. For instance,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  a int,
  b int,
  UNIQUE ( greatest(a,b), least(a,b) )
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,2); -- works
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2,1); -- explodes
```

I know SQL Server can create computed columns, and using that I thought I could build what I want..

```
CREATE TABLE f (
  a int,
  b int,
  g AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN a ELSE b END),
  l AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN b ELSE a END),
  UNIQUE(g,l)
);
```

But I get, **Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Line 1**

> `CREATE TABLE` failed because the following `SET` options have incorrect settings: '`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`'. Verify that `SET` options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Followed by, **Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Line 1**

> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

So I guess that this can not be done with a `UNIQUE` index. Is this currently possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

@Dan Guzman answered it in the comments,

> The error simply means the quoted identifier session setting is off, which must be on for computed column indexes. Try adding `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` before the `CREATE TABLE' script.

Code,

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
CREATE TABLE f (
  a int,
  b int,
  g AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN a ELSE b END),
  l AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN b ELSE a END),
  UNIQUE(g,l)
);
```

From the docs on quoted identifiers

> `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` must be ON when you are creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views. If `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `OFF`, `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements on tables with indexes on **computed columns or indexed views will fail.** For more information about required `SET` option settings with indexed views and indexes on computed columns, see "Considerations When You Use the SET Statements" in SET Statements (Transact-SQL).

Interestingly, it's not the default. Despite what they say. They lie. Their official client, `sqlcmd` requires the flag `-I Enable Quoted Identifiers`,

> When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON` (default), all strings delimited by double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers. [...] This can be configured in ODBC data sources, in ODBC connection attributes, or OLE DB connection properties. The default for `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is OFF for connections from DB-Library applications.

I'm guessing `sqlcmd` is a "DB-Library application", and what Microsoft means to say is the default gets default-changed by the default in their own client. That's pretty much inane gobbledygook.

Comment: [`SQLCMD` currently uses ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) rather than the long deprecated DBLIB API. I think it defaults to `QUOTED IDENTIFIER OFF` for compatibility with it's OSQL and ISQL predecessors.